# Can I install IE4 on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I'm experimenting a bit with older browsers, so in addition to some later versions of IE, I thought I'd try installing IE4 on a virtual machine.

This is in one of those pre-installed virtual machines by [modern.IE](https://www.modern.ie/); I downloaded the one with IE6 and made a copy and then tried to install IE4 on it, but I hit a snag. The IE4 installer says that there is already a newer version of IE installed. (Duh...)

OK, so I removed IE6 from the list of Windows Components with the Control Panel, but that doesn't help. The IE4 installer keeps insisting that there's a newer version installed.

Anybody got any ideas? Can I remove the installed IE version more thoroughly than simply unchecking its checkbox in the Control Panel?
If I could get an installation of Windows without any IE installed, that would be nice, but AFAIK Windows XP always came with IE active by default. So, what can I do? I searched the web, but I couldn't find a single page that explained how to get around the problem of a newer version already present.

Comment: Hmm. IE 4 was released in 1997 and superseded in in 1999. Why do you want to run a browser that is 16 yearsoldand full of bugs? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Try installing Windows 95 or 98.

Comment: Like I said, experimenting a bit. I've also got Netscape 3.0 installed. Call it a hobby.

Comment: @Paul That could be a solution. Time to delve through my old box of CDs under the bed!

Comment: No; The lowest IE supported by XP is IE6.

Comment: You can run IE2 in any windows OS, but only renders text.

Comment: [See this page](http://mcakins.com/2013/09/22/lets-run-internet-explorer-4-on-windows-8/)